# ATD module for Python 3.6

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x

I want to use ATD module in python, I downloaded it throught the command line pip install ATD, and it was Successfully installed. But when I wanna use it in python, it says that the module is not found, does anyone know what's wrong with it, and how can i fix it?

```
>>> import ATD
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    import ATD
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ATD'
```

Comment: Do you have both Python 2 and Python 3 installed? If so, try installing the package with `pip3` instead of `pip`.

Comment: I tried this but the error is remaining :/

Comment: Exactly which module are you using? A link to its documentation or home page would be helpful.

Comment: This is the link: **https://pypi.python.org/pypi/atd/0.1.5**
What I am trying to reach is this code `import ATD
ATD.setDefaultKey("your API key")
errors = ATD.checkDocument("Looking too the water. Fixing your writing typoss.")
for error in errors:
 print "%s error for: %s **%s**" % (error.type, error.precontext, error.string)
 print "some suggestions: %s" % (", ".join(error.suggestions),)`
//Expected output://

`grammar error for: Looking **too the**
some suggestions: to the
spelling error for: writing **typoss**
some suggestions: typos`

Comment: The module in that package is lower case (`atd.py`). Try executing `import atd` instead.